# iOS possible to access the super class iBoutlets objects in my subclass?

Tags: ios, iboutlet, subclassing

I want to access super class iBoutlets objetcs in my subclass. Is that possible?. I am trying in the following way but am always getting nil.

Here is my code:
My super class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SuperClassA : UIViewController {

}

@property (weak, nonatomic, getter=getDummyView) IBOutlet UIView *dummyView;

@end

@implementation SuperClassA
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    SubClassB *obj = [SubClassB new];
    [obj printSuperClassiBouletObject];
}

@end
```

my subclass:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SubClassB : SuperClassA {

}

@end

@implementation SubClassB

-(void)printSuperClassiBouletObject
{
    NSLog(@"view: %@", [self getDummyView]);
}
@end
```

The above code gives me nil value always. Any idea how to get the actual iBoutlet object?. But when i pass the iBoutlet as an function argument then the object was not nil. In the super class i tried strong property, using @synthesize in implementation file but no helps. Any help that really might be appreciated.

Comment: IBOutlet isn't a class name, but just a marker to the interface builder stuff so it can identify names that are significant to the interface.  It's not significant to your code, only to the XIB.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing special about `IBOutlet` relative to the scope rules.  You can inherit any property from super by including its declaration in the subclass.  The simple way to do this is by placing those property declarations in the superclass's public interface (in superclass.h).  Since we know that the subclass must import that, we know that everything in there will be available to the subclass.

A more complicated arrangement is required if you'd like the subclass to access the property but not other classes.  These "protected" declarations need to go into a third header file that only the super and subclass import.

In other words... (simple case):

```
// MySuper.h
@interface MySuper : NSObject
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *someOutlet;
@end

// MySub.h
#import "MySuper.h"

@interface MySub : MySuper
// stuff for my sub
@end
```

Now both `MySuper` and `MySub` can refer to `someOutlet`

For "protected", something like this:

```
// MySuper.h
@interface MySuper : NSObject
// only public stuff here
@end

// MySuper-protected.h
@interface MySuper ()
@property (weak,nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *someOutlet;
@end

// MySuper.m
#import "MySuper.h"
#import "MySuper-protected.h"

// MySub.h
// same as simple case

// MySub.m
#import "MySub.h"
#import "MySuper-protected.h"
```

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that the problem is here:

```
SubClassB *obj = [SubClassB new];
[obj printSuperClassiBouletObject];
```

New will use default initializer, that will try to load nib with your class name, which is SubClassB. Do you have SubClassB.xib that set the outlet your project? If not, then SubClassB will be initialized with empty properties, by the default objc initializer.

Try this:

```
SubClassB *obj = [[SubClassB alloc] initWithNibName:@"SuperClassA"]; //or xib name that SuperClassA uses to initialize
```

Answer (score 0):

Finally, i was able to achieve this by using this way!!!!

In my subclass i changed the method to:

```
-(void)printSuperClassiBouletObject:(SuperClassA*)superClassObj
```

and in my super class i am calling this way:

```
SubClassB *obj = [SubClassB new];
[obj printSuperClassiBouletObject:self];
```

And in my subclass i was access the super class objects and its variable from the super class instance it self.
Thanks for all the help !!!!!! :-)